# Why CrudRepository.save() ignore FetchType.EAGER when returning created object?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring Data Jpa in my app. There are two entities in the application. The entity `Film`:

```
//annotations omitted
public class Film {

    // other annotations omitted
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> users;
    
    ...
```

and `User`:

```
//annotations omitted
public class User {

    // other annotations omitted
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Film> films;
    
    ...
```

And DTO for `Film`:

```
public class FilmTo implements Serializable {
    private List<Integer> userIds; // i using users ids instead of users for simplify REST-requests
}
```

And the app has repositories classes:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudFilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Integer> {
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CrudUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Ok. This code using, when i want to save new film:

```
@Service
public class FilmService {

    @Autowired
    private CrudFilmRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private CrudUserRepository userRepository;

    public Film save(FilmTo filmTo) {
        Film film = new Film();
        film.setUsers(Arrays.stream(filmTo.getUserIds())
            .map(crudUserRepository::getOne)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return repository.save(film);
    }
```

The problems occurs when save() returns created Film, and i want works with users in List in returned Films. Throws LazyInitializationException even if `User list <User>` is marked as FetchType.EAGER!

Why crudRepository ignore FetchType.EAGER, when i use users lazy references for initialize new Film and try save this film?

Comment: Side note: eagerly fetching a JPA relationship will bite you in the future (especially a OneToMany or ManyToMany), I'd rather have them lazy loaded and explicitly fetched at querying time if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save()` just delegates to `EntityManager.persist` or `EntityManager.merge` and returns the object returned by `EntityManager.merge` or the one you passed in. The `FetchType` does not play a role here. If you want the association to be loaded, you can use `refresh` or `findOne`.